# Can telegram bot be configured to allow only one user to add the bot to a group?

Tags: python-3.x, telegram, telegram-bot, aiogram

I'm making a Telegram Bot with aiogram3 and I need to make bot to be addable to groups only by admin of my bot. Is there any way to do it?

I tried code below but it only works for private chats.

```
@dp.chat_join_request()
async def request_handler(update: types.ChatJoinRequest):
    await update.decline()
```

Answer (score 0):

No thats not possible.

A group owner can add a bot the group.

The bot could however catch the join update and call [`leaveChat`](https://core.telegram.org/bots/api#leavechat) to leave it if it's not whitelisted;

> Use this method for your bot to leave a group, supergroup or channel. Returns *True* on success.